# CodeIngiter model doesn't save in the session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session-variables, codeigniter-3

I need to add in a sessione some variables that I obtain after I do login. This is my code in my model.php:

```
function login($username,$password)
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$username."'");
        $row = $query->row();

        if (isset($row))
        {
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged','isLogged');
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

The proble is that when I check the value in the session (google chrome) I doesn't read the "logged" parameter. Anyone can help me?

Comment: How do you check the session with google chrome???

Comment: oopen google console-->Application-->Session Storage

Comment: No... you are misunderstanding sessions here, these sessions are stored in the server and not in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is the browser session storage. PHP/CodeIgniter lives on the server and therefore will not use this storage.

You will find your variable set in the PHP `$_SESSION` superglobal. You can access it like so:

```
$_SESSION['logged'];
```

Alternatively, you can use the CodeIgniter magic getter method:

```
$this->session->logged;
```

You can find more info on CodeIgniter sessions [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data).

Hope this helps.